# on click of notification "launching activity"has Bundle savedInstanceState as null in android

Tags: android

On click of notification in launching `Activity` i see Bundle `savedInstanceState` as null my android manifest code for launching activity is as follow:

```
 <activity
            android:name=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
```

Why is `savedInstanceState` coming null in this activity?

Any help is appreciated for solving the above problem

Comment: Why are you setting `android:taskAffinity=""` ?

Comment: without sending also savedInstanceState is null